# xgboost f-score

Tags: python, decision-trees, xgboost

I'm using xgboost package on python 3.5 for time base predication
The result of the f-score Partial dependence on the order of the columns in data frame.
The rmse of the predication is a same.

for example: 
In case of that columns order:

```
columns_order = ['MONTH', 'MDAY', 'WEEK', 'WDAY', 'YEAR', 'DYEAR', 'START_TIME_NORMALIZE', '1_last_x', '2_last_x',
                 '3_last_x', '4_last_x', '5_last_x', 'EPISODE_NUMBER', 'SEASON_NUMBER', 'pre_1_last_x', 'pre_2_last_x',
                 'pre_3_last_x', 'pre_4_last_x', 'pre_5_last_x']
```

The fscore result is:

```
fscore = [('START_TIME_NORMALIZE', 7910), ('DYEAR', 7518), ('1_last_x', 7108), ('MDAY', 6977), ('WDAY', 6797),
          ('WEEK', 6319), ('2_last_x', 5490), ('pre_1_last_x', 5269), ('5_last_x', 5202), ('3_last_x', 5096),
          ('EPISODE_NUMBER', 5057), ('4_last_x', 4723), ('SEASON_NUMBER', 4442), ('MONTH', 4097),
          ('pre_2_last_x', 3502), ('pre_5_last_x', 3401), ('pre_3_last_x', 3221), ('YEAR', 2956),
          ('pre_4_last_x', 2827)]
```

And in case of that columns order:

```
columns_order = ['1_last_x', '2_last_x', '3_last_x', '4_last_x', '5_last_x', 'MDAY', 'WEEK', 'WDAY', 'MONTH', 'YEAR',
                 'DYEAR', 'START_TIME_NORMALIZE', 'EPISODE_NUMBER', 'SEASON_NUMBER', 'pre_1_last_x', 'pre_2_last_x',
                 'pre_3_last_x', 'pre_4_last_x', 'pre_5_last_x']
```

The fscore result is:

```
fscore = [('1_last_x', 9909), ('START_TIME_NORMALIZE', 9407), ('DYEAR', 9005), ('WEEK', 8624), ('MDAY', 8202),
          ('WDAY', 7726), ('2_last_x', 6916), ('3_last_x', 6533), ('EPISODE_NUMBER', 6023), ('pre_1_last_x', 5825),
          ('5_last_x', 5703), ('4_last_x', 5232), ('SEASON_NUMBER', 5093), ('pre_2_last_x', 4477),
          ('pre_3_last_x', 3672), ('pre_4_last_x', 3564), ('pre_5_last_x', 3382), ('YEAR', 2892), ('MONTH', 1060)]
```

The average of the `n_last_x` variances is `0.00636`